# Aggregate query grouping

Tags: sql-server

The query below seems to work despite being wrong.

The `Color` column doesn't belong in an aggregate function but I don't want to group by `Color`. I want to return the color for the minimum priority grouped by Vehicle.

I hope the below is enough to work with - I was hoping for a quick answer but will go into more detail if necessary.

```
SELECT alert.VehicleID,
       min(hotcol.[Priority]) as [Priority]
       min(hotcol.Color) as Color,
FROM [ALERTS] alert
    INNER JOIN [HOTLISTS] hotlist ON alert.[HotlistID] = hotlist.[HotlistID]
    INNER JOIN [HOTLIST_COLORS] hotcol ON hotlist.ColorID = hotcol.ColorID
WHERE VehicleID = 17513851
GROUP BY alert.VehicleID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do this. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT 
     alert.VehicleID,
     hotcol.Color,
     hotcol.[Priority],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY alert.VehicleID 
                       ORDER BY hotcol.[Priority]) AS RN
   FROM [ALERTS] alert
   INNER JOIN [HOTLISTS] hotlist ON alert.[HotlistID] = hotlist.[HotlistID]
   INNER JOIN [HOTLIST_COLORS] hotcol ON hotlist.ColorID = hotcol.ColorID
   WHERE VehicleID = 17513851
)
SELECT 
  VehicleID,
  Color,
  [Priority]
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` function will give a ranking number for each `alert.VehicleID` and each group will be ordered by `priority`. Then `WHERE rn = 1` will filter out all the rows except the minimum one which has `rn = 1`.

Comment: Looks promising but I'm getting a few errors such as `The multi-part identifier could not be bound` for every item in the column list and `Incorrect Syntax near PARTITION`

Comment: @user1405195 - Comma is missed between 3rd and 4th column inside `CTE`. Edited check now